# How to remove every second space regex?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, spaces

I have this string:

```
LP-----A0000001------A0000002
```

I need regexp which will format this string into this string(removes every - after every first one).

Something like this:

```
LP-A0000001-A0000002
```

I am trying to do it in php with `preg_replace()`, but I am not able to accomplish it.

Comment: If your text is not littered (literally thousands) with single dash sequences, just use a global find `-+` and replace `-`

Answer (score 2):

You could try to match two or more spaces and replace with a single space:

```
$out = preg_replace('/  +/', ' ', $in);
```

For your example, it'll be:

```
$out = preg_replace('/--+/', '-', $in);
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/iT3bL3)

Comment: imo cleaner syntax: `-{2,}`

Comment: @tenub I prefer `--+` since I usually want my code not to take too much horizontal space, but I guess that's just a matter of preference. And I might have been doing too many golf ^^;

Answer (score 1):

for spaces:

```
$result = preg_replace('~(?<= ) +~', '', $str);
```

`(?<=...)` is a lookbehind and means *preceded by*

for all kind of white-spaces:

```
$result = preg_replace('~(?<=\s)\s+~', '', $str);
```

for horizontal white-spaces:

```
$result = preg_replace('~(?<=\h)\h+~', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only looking to replace the groups of hyphens with a single one, you can use the following regex to match on them for any length:

```
$str = 'LP-----A0000001------A0000002';
$result = preg_replace('/(\-+)/', '-', $str);
```

Comment: The capture group is unnecessary (and costs steps).  the `-` doesn't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Use: `/-{2,}/` on `LP-----A0000001------A0000002` ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7UKeEG/1))

This will match 2 or more hyphens and will only actually make two replacements total.

Using: `/-+/` will also match single hyphens and replace them with themselves (wasted effort / no change).

Using a lookbehind will be less efficient because lookarounds cost more steps to complete.